# Unit testing by passing runtime parameters to java reflect method

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods

I am making a class object using the a java bean in my code. Then I am calling a particular method of that class obj

```
public static void runUnitTest(String className, String methodName, List<Object> inputParams, Object expectedReturnValue){
                try {
        // Make the class object to be tested on
        Object classObj = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
        Method calledMethod = classObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName,inputParams.get(0).getClass());
        Object returnVal = calledMethod.invoke(classObj,inputParams.get(0));
        }catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                        | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

I call it this way :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        List<Object> inputParams = new ArrayList<Object>();
        inputParams.add(new BigDecimal(1234));
        runUnitTest("NumberTest","getOutputNumber",inputParams,new BigDecimal(5678));
    }
```

The code of NumberTest:

```
public class NumberTest{

    public BigDecimal getOutputNumber(BigDecimal numberId) {
        if(numberId.intValue() == 1234)
        {
            return new BigDecimal(5678);
        }else 
            return new BigDecimal(0);
    }

    public BigDecimal getAdditionalOutputNumber(BigDecimal numberId, String additionalInfo) {
        if(numberId.intValue() == 1234 && "Pass".equals(additionalInfo))
        {
            return new BigDecimal(5678);
        }else 
            return new BigDecimal(0);
    }
}
```

This works fine as I know that the method `getOutputNumber` has only one parameter. But when I have to call the same code for multiple methods where number of parameters differ (e.g. `getAdditionalOutputNumber`) I can't use the same code. I don't want to use a multiple if else or case block on the basis of size of inputParams. 
Is there a generic way of calling the below :

```
Method calledMethod = classObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName,**?? What to pass here ??**);
Object returnVal = calledMethod.invoke(classObj,**?? What to pass here ??**);
```

Comment: @RC. I will anyways club the code with either of framework. Although, it would be better if you advise after reading the question.

Comment: Sure, let me take it back..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to build suitable arrays from the list of parameters to call the reflection API.

```
Class[] types = new Class[inputParams.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Object param:inputParams) {
    types[i++] = param.getClass();
}
Method calledMethod = classObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName,types);
Object returnVal = calledMethod.invoke(classObj,inputParams.toArray());
```

There might be some issues with primitive types and null values.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this?